# SQL to generate IsNew column based on ID, DataLoad dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create an SQL view and having trouble in deriving IsNew(Boolean) column based on ID and reporting date fields. I wanted to write a CASE statement in select query. My data looks like this:

```
 ReportingDate  ID
02/09/2016  392
02/09/2016  393
02/09/2016  394
09/09/2016  394
09/09/2016  400
16/09/2016  400
16/09/2016  407
```

I wanted to derive IsNew(Boolean) column for above data to see whether the ID field is occurring for first time. For example: ID: 407 on date: 16/09/2016 is newly created as I cant find the same ID in previous reportingdate's. whereas ID: 400 is not newly created as this exists in previous load: 09/09/2016.

I want output something like this: Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
 ReportingDate  ID  IsNew
02/09/2016  392 TRUE
02/09/2016  393 TRUE
02/09/2016  394 TRUE
09/09/2016  394 FALSE
09/09/2016  400 TRUE
16/09/2016  400 FALSE
16/09/2016  407 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Window function and Subquery

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (ReportingDate DATE, ID INT)

INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'02/09/2016',103) , 392 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'02/09/2016',103) , 393 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'02/09/2016',103) , 394 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'09/09/2016',103) , 394 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'09/09/2016',103) , 400 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'16/09/2016',103) , 400 
UNION ALL
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,'16/09/2016',103) , 407
```

Now select like below

```
SELECT ReportingDate
    ,ID
    ,CASE WHEN SNO = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS IsNew
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ReportingDate) AS SNO
        ,ReportingDate,ID
    FROM #TAB
    ) A
```

**Result**

```
+---------------+-----+-------+
| ReportingDate | ID  | IsNew |
+---------------+-----+-------+
| 2016-09-02    | 392 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-02    | 393 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-02    | 394 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-09    | 394 | FALSE |
| 2016-09-09    | 400 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-16    | 400 | FALSE |
| 2016-09-16    | 407 | TRUE  |
+---------------+-----+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it's

```
declare @table table (date date,id int)

insert into @table (date,id) values('02/09/2016',392)
insert into @table (date,id) values('02/09/2016',393)
insert into @table (date,id) values('02/09/2016',394)
insert into @table (date,id) values('09/09/2016',394)
insert into @table (date,id) values('09/09/2016',400)
insert into @table (date,id) values('16/09/2016',400)
insert into @table (date,id) values('16/09/2016',407)

select
    case when IsNew = 1 then 'True' else 'False' end as IsNew,
    Date,
    Id
from (
select
    row_number() over(partition by id order by date asc) as IsNew,*
from @table) as a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use row_number for getting this:

```
select *,
    case 
        when Row_Number() over (
                partition by ID 
                order by ReportingDate
                ) = 1
            then 'TRUE'
        else 'FALSE'
        end as IsNew
from yourtable
```

Your input table :

```
create table #yourreporting (ReportingDate date, ID int)

Insert into #yourreporting
(    ReportingDate  , ID ) values
 ('09-02-2016',  392)
,('09-02-2016',  393)
,('09-02-2016',  394)
,('09-09-2016',  394)
,('09-09-2016',  400)
,('09-16-2016',  400)
,('09-16-2016',  407)
```

Results:

```
+---------------+-----+-------+
| ReportingDate | ID  | IsNew |
+---------------+-----+-------+
| 2016-09-02    | 392 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-02    | 393 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-02    | 394 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-09    | 394 | FALSE |
| 2016-09-09    | 400 | TRUE  |
| 2016-09-16    | 400 | FALSE |
| 2016-09-16    | 407 | TRUE  |
+---------------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: The above will give True for all records which is not OP needs

Comment: Yep it is partition by Id only for this requirement.. Thanks Shakeer

Answer (score 0):

You can join back into the same table and look for matches or `null`s:

```
select a.ID
      ,case when b.ID is null then 1 else 0 end as IsNew
from YourTable a
    left join (select ID
                     ,max(ReportingDate) as MaxReportingDate
               from YourTable
               group by ID
              ) b
        on(a.ID = b.ID
           and a.ReportingDate < b.ReportingDate
          )
```

Depending on your preference for readability, you could also do this as a `CTE`:

```
with c as
(
    select ID
          ,max(ReportingDate) as MaxReportingDate
    from YourTable
    group by ID
)
select a.ID
      ,case when b.ID is null then 1 else 0 end as IsNew
from YourTable a
    left join c
        on(a.ID = c.ID
           and a.ReportingDate < c.ReportingDate
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Table , insert temp values and result query :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestData](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [ReportingDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([id], [ReportingDate]) VALUES (392, CAST(N'2016-09-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([id], [ReportingDate]) VALUES (393, CAST(N'2016-09-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([id], [ReportingDate]) VALUES (394, CAST(N'2016-09-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([id], [ReportingDate]) VALUES (394, CAST(N'2016-09-09 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([id], [ReportingDate]) VALUES (400, CAST(N'2016-09-09 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([id], [ReportingDate]) VALUES (400, CAST(N'2016-09-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[TestData] ([id], [ReportingDate]) VALUES (407, CAST(N'2016-09-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO


with cte as (
select s.*
,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by s.id,s.[ReportingDate] ) rn
from dbo.[TestData] s  
)

select c.id,c.[ReportingDate],
case when exists( select * from cte c2 where c2.rn < c.rn and c2.id = c.id ) then 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END IsNew
 from CTE c
```